# markdown subset

Tags: javascript, jquery, markdown

I am looking for a markdown parser, preferably Javascript, that I can customize. In particular, I would like to remove the option for using actual HTML tags.
I tried editing the source of showdown, but couldn't figure it out.
Jquery integration would also be nice, though not a must.

BTW, since I have started looking into markdown, I found a bunch of references on the SO blog/podcast to a rewrite of the markdown parser using a lexer/tokenizer/parser. I'm not really sure what that means, but I gather it will mean an easier to read and edit parser. I haven't been able to find any more details about it. Did this ever happen, or was it just toyed around with for a while and dropped?

One more thing: Is the SO markdown editor+preview+toolbar available anywhere? How about as a Jquery plugin? Are they still using the WMD-editor, or a rewrite?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/reverse-engineering-the-wmd-editor/) from *2008* the creator of the WMD project is no longer taking care of WMD. If you see the source of SO, you can see that they are still using the WMD editor, it may be slightly modified though.

As for the alternatives:

- **[markitup](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/downloads/demo.php?id=markupsets/markdown)** (using jQuery)
- [**derobins fork** of the WMD](https://github.com/derobins/wmd)

Comment: StackExchange has an open source fork of WMD/Showdown http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/